# How to set fancybox height auto and full width to top page?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I want to place a window at the top of the page, so that the width is on the whole window and the height depends on the content (auto). How can i do this?

Comment: Could you share what all have you tried ? Have you tried google or search on stackoverflow ?

Comment: If you are using fancybox v3, then simply use CSS to set content width 100vw.